# Renaming raster files with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.5

I have multiple raster layers (TIFF) with names following this pattern:

```
"euj_LANDSAT7_250m_20170101_v2"
"euj_LANDSAT7_250m_20170102_v2">
"euj_LANDSAT7_250m_20170103_v2">
...
```

and I would like to rename them to follow this pattern:

```
LANDSAT7_170101.tif"
LANDSAT7_170102.tif"
LANDSAT7_170103.tif"
...
```

I've tried to use this code (edited according to PolyGeo's answer):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "E:/Training/TryArcpy/test01_2017"

in_data = arcpy.ListRasters()

for raster in in_data:
    out_data = raster[4:13] + raster[20:26] + fileExtension
    arcpy.Rename_management(in_data, out_data)
```

The message I get is:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", 
line 4537, in Rename
raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Is this because I have a raster list as in_data? If yes, how do I loop through multiple rasters without using a list, or use a list in appropriate way? And if no, what could be the problem?

Comment: I've edited the question and the code according to PolyGeo's answer, and I get a new error, described above.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend renaming using `os` in this because your TIFF files may have associated files like world files (*`*.tfw`) that will be missed.

Also, the `os` module is unaware of the setting you have for `arcpy.env.workspace`.

I would use the [Rename](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/rename.htm) tool instead:

> Changes the name of a dataset. This includes a wide variety of data
>   types, among them feature dataset, **raster**, table, and shapefile.

Take care to distinguish the raster's layer name from its data source.

Answer (score 0):

It is never good practice to slice a string (e.g. `raster[4:13]`) when renaming data because all that would be required for an error is one extra character in the string. instead, try to split the name up into parts by a common character if possible. In your case, you can split the string into parts by the underscore `_` character. For example:

```
>>> name = "euj_LANDSAT7_250m_20170101_v2.tif"
>>> parts = name.split("_")
>>> parts
['euj', 'LANDSAT7', '250m', '20170101', 'v2.tif']
>>> final_name = parts[1] + "_" + parts[3] + ".tif"
>>> final_name
'LANDSAT7_20170101.tif'
```

I also see you have an undefined variable `fileExtension` which could be causing the error.

Applying the example to your case:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "E:/Training/TryArcpy/test01_2017"

in_data = arcpy.ListRasters()

for raster in in_data:
    parts = raster.split("_")
    out_data = parts[1] + "_" + parts[3] + ".tif"

    arcpy.Rename_management(in_data, out_data)
```

Comment: This looks good, but I still get the same error (the entire error message seen in my question). I looked at other threads with similar errors but didn't find anything useful that would help with this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you fix the variable issue?

Comment: I used ".tif" instead of the fileExtension.